# Sympy cannot compute integrate(sec(x+1)**2, x)

Tags: sympy

I find it strange that `sympy` cannot evaluate `integrate(sec(x+1)**2, x)` when it can evaluate `integrate(sec(x)**2, x)`. I've restricted the domain of `x` just in case and I still can't evaluate the integral of `sec(x+1)**2.

```
x, y, z = symbols('x, y, z', real=True, positive=True)
```

Why does sympy struggle with this?

Answer (score 0):

This is arguably a bug in SymPy but you can work around by rewriting sec:

```
>>> integrate(sec(x+1)**2, x)
Integral(sec(x + 1)**2, x)
>>> _.rewrite(cos)  # sin or tan works too
Integral(cos(x + 1)**(-2), x)
>>> _.doit()
-2*tan(x/2 + 1/2)/(tan(x/2 + 1/2)**2 - 1)
>>> simplify(_)
tan(x + 1)
```

Comment: Ideally sympy should be able to do this so it's either a bug or at least a valid feature request. Best to open an issue on github.